# Creating a content formatting for user view

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

i want to make my own format content, I already done with the paragraph and the list as well but there are some problems that i can't solve it. This is the problem:

I can't get the first **[li]** and the last **[li]** in the group, 
ex:

```
some text
more text here
[li]......[/li] /*
[li]......[/li]  * here is one group that will be wrapped with <ul></ul>
[li]......[/li]  *
there are some text here as well
[li]......[/li] /* this will be wrapped with <ul></ul> too
[li]......[/li]  *
```

And here is the conditions that i want:

1. If **[li]** is found in the content then it'll coat it with **ul bracket** and then replace all **[li]** with **li tags**.
2. All **\n** will be replaced with **[br]**
3. **[br]** will be exploded to know what is a paragraph, and what is the list group

This is what i stored in database

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed blandit molestie lacus id consequat. Cras varius tincidunt fermentum. Morbi bibendum risus nec ligula ultrices pretium. Sed bibendum ultrices sem, interdum dignissim risus imperdiet eget. Cras viverra est risus. Donec pretium commodo dui, eu vehicula massa sollicitudin quis. Praesent sit amet purus libero. Morbi dignissim metus nec convallis posuere. Pellentesque enim tellus, efficitur sed volutpat at, pellentesque in urna. Nam accumsan laoreet tellus, sed dapibus urna congue nec. Mauris pharetra dui lorem. Aenean imperdiet nibh erat, sed vulputate ex aliquam sed. Sed eu eros non lorem ornare faucibus sit amet id elit.
[li]Sunrise and mountain view early in the morning[/li]
[li]Breakfast in the in rice field[/li]
[li]Explore the Yeh Mataan river and the water[/li]
[li]Lunch and Napping with the beach view[/li]
[li]Enjoy the beach and witness the sunset[/li]
Donec auctor ipsum ipsum, vitae rutrum tellus porttitor vitae. Praesent sodales sollicitudin mauris ac viverra. Aenean sodales odio ac volutpat mattis. Nunc quis sapien ut nisi ultrices consectetur.
```

this is the code so far

```
    private $html_format = array(
                    "\n[li]" => '<li>',
                    "\n"     => '[br]',
                    '[li]'   => '<li>',
                    '[/li]'  => '</li>',
                    '[b]'    => '<b>',
                    '[/b]'   => '</b>'
            );


    public function description_decoder($data) 
    {
            foreach ($this->html_format AS $format_key => $format_value) {
                    $data = str_replace($format_key, $format_value, $data);
            }

            $exploded_data = explode('[br]', $data);
            $decoded_data  = '';
            print_r($exploded_data);

            $list = 0;

            foreach ($exploded_data AS $paragraph) {
                    if (!empty($paragraph)) {
                            if (strpos($paragraph, '</li>')) {
                                    if ($list == 0) $paragraph = '<ul>' . $paragraph;
                                    elseif ($list == 1) $paragraph = $paragraph . '</ul>';

                            }
                            else $paragraph = '<p>' . $paragraph . '</p>';

                            $decoded_data .= $paragraph;
                    }
            }


            return $decoded_data;
    }
```

Please help, i don't know how to achieve this

Comment: What you're trying to do is much like BB code, there is also markdown which is much nicer and most people know how to use it, plus there are many editor and libs to convert it from and to HTML. Hopefully, your still filtering out all HTML from user input and running htmlentities on your output.

Comment: Yeah i know there are many editor, but i want to make one by myself, and i still filtering all of them, this function is only to decode the html, the output is not from here. But thanks for reminding me @LawrenceCherone